# Run redis-cli when redis is running like a service

Tags: redis, redis-cli

I have a problem with Redis and redis-cli.

I have running Redis like a service in windows, like you can see in the picture
[image]

but when I try to run "redis-cli" it doesn't anything, the console is frozen
[image]
I need to monitoring all messages with MONITORING command.

Can you help me please!?

Regards.

Comment: Open a Command Prompt and run `redis-cli ping` and see if it replies `pong`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell the same, the console is frozen like in the picture

Comment: Try temporarily disabling any firewall.

Comment: What does it say in the Redis log file?

Comment: I have disabling the firewall and de log don't say nothing (the last register in the log file is very old)